# Global beforeEach and afterEach in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

In each spec I have `beforeEach` and `afterEach` statements. Is it possible to add it somehow globally to avoid code duplication between specs ?

Comment: You can use any one of these as per your requirement. `onPrepare()`, `onComplete()`, `onCleanUp()` & `afterLaunch()`.  Check it here https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L200

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar, your comment seems to be quality.. you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @Michal Someone pasted that as answer.

Answer (score 4):

Purpose of `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` functions are to add a block of repetitive code that you would need to execute every time you start or complete executing each spec(`it`). There are other ways to add generalised code to avoid code repetition, here are few -

- If you have a piece of code that you would require to run only once before starting a test suite(`describe`), then you can use `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()` functions that jasmine provides.
- If you want to run a piece of code that you want to run only once when the execution starts before starting all the test scripts, then add it in your `onPrepare()` and `onComplete()` function.
- If you want to add a piece of code that should run even before protractor has started instantiating itself or after it has shut itself down, then use `beforeLaunch` and `afterLaunch`.

So it all depends on the scenario that you want to use them in. Hope it helps.

Comment: neither of the above solves OP question which is also mine: how do you run a piece of code before EACH of the specs, but only write this once (i.e. not duplicate it in each of the specs files)?

Comment: Hi @OvidiuDolha , the answer to both OP's question and your question was actually "No", written metaphorically and so I gave few options. As far as I know, this feature is not in jasmine at all. As part of the workaround, you can create a global function and then call it in beforeEach() in each test script file.

Comment: roger, makes sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

My team has the same desire, to run bits of boilerplate code at the start of every test file. From the discussion here, it doesn't sound like there are hooks to globally add to the `beforeEach()`, `afterEach()`, etc.

However, we *do* use the `onPrepare()` function to abbreviate the amount of before/after boilerplate code that gets repeated in each spec file. Below is a `beforeAll()` example, but the pattern could be used for `beforeEach()/afterEach()`. In this case, we're setting up test users in the database with a DataSeeder class, which we do in the outer-most `describe()` block in every spec file.  (I'm also leaving in my `catchProtractorErrorInLocation` pattern, because it's super useful for us.)

In protractor.conf.ts add boilerplate code to `browser.params` object.

```
  onPrepare: function () {
    ...
    const browser = require('protractor').browser;
    // Define the ConsoleHelper & DataSeeder instances, which will be used by all tests.
    const DataSeeder = require('./e2e/support/data-seeder.js');
    browser.params.dataSeeder = new DataSeeder();

    browser.catchProtractorErrorInLocation = (error, location) => {
      throw new Error(`Error in ${location}\n     ${error}`);
    };
    browser.catchProtractorErrorInBeforeAll = (error) => browser.catchProtractorErrorInLocation(error, 'beforeAll()');

    // Return a promise that resolves when DataSeeder is connected to service and ready to go
    return browser.params.dataSeeder.waitForConnect();
  },
```

With that in place, we can easily do `beforeAll()` setup code in an abbreviated set of lines.

```
  beforeAll(() => {
    return browser.params.dataSeeder.createTestUsers()
      .catch(browser.catchProtractorErrorInBeforeAll);
  });
```

You obviously need to do different things in your setup, but you can see how the pattern can apply.