# Protractor : Function to run at the end of all tests

Tags: mysql, protractor

Just like the onPrepare() function runs once before any of my tests is there a function to run once at the end of all tests?

Here is my situation. I have a global.db.connect() in onPrepare(). Various tests use this global variable to run mysql queries. The tests run on multiple browsers in parallel. Once my tests finish running, I'd like to do a db.disconnect().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global beforeEach and afterEach in protractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566341/global-beforeeach-and-aftereach-in-protractor)

Comment: The answer is provided here ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566341/global-beforeeach-and-aftereach-in-protractor

Answer (score 1):

posted the question too soon. The solution is to use this

```
 onComplete: function() {
    // At this point, tests will be done but global objects will still be
    // available.
  }
```

Documentation
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js